# Why do I receive the following AttributeError when testing a class method with unittest: 'class' object has no attribute 'testing method'?

Tags: python, unit-testing, attributeerror

For the sake of practicing to code, I am trying to program a very simple game. When trying to run a test on a (private) class method, I receive the following error: `AttributeError: 'LivingBeing' object has no attribute '_Test_Class_Methods__lose_hp'`

More elaborate:

I have a class named "LivingBeing" in the file classes.py.

```
class LivingBeing:

def __init__(self, name, hp=100):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp

def __lose_hp(self, number=20, decimal_percentage=1):
    self.hp = self.hp - (21 - number)*decimal_percentage
    return self.hp
```

Now I would like to test said __lose_hp method, and I tried this with the following code:

```
import sys, unittest
sys.path.append("/Users/angel/OneDrive/Dokumente/Studium/CL/Programmieren/git_projects/fantasticgame/")

from classes import LivingBeing

class Test_Class_Methods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.livingbeing = LivingBeing("Life")

    def test_lose_hp(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.livingbeing.__lose_hp(20), 99, "Should be 99")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

What I tried so far:

- I found some information that it was most likely an ImportError, so I
  tried the "sys.path.append"-statement according to how a similar
  problem was solved. So, if I were to leave it out, I would receive
  the same error message. The file "classes.py" and the testing file
  are in this same folder.
- At first, I did not have the setUp method, however it had solved a somewhat similar
  problem for someone else ([namely here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682188/assertion-error-testing-attributes-and-methods-in-a-class)), so I tried it - same error    message for
  me however.
- I also didn't have the return statement in the class method itself at
  first, about which I very much understand why it would throw an Error
  by now (because the return value would be None).
- The very classic try to just restart (the computer) and retry before posting also did not help.
- There was a point at which I tried to make "Test_Class_Methods"
  inherit from both, the unittest.Testcase and LivingBeing, but this
  caused the same error again.

Looked like this:

```
class Test_Class_Methods(unittest.TestCase, LivingBeing):

    def setUp(self):
        self.livingbeing = LivingBeing("Life")

    def test_lose_hp(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.livingbeing.__lose_hp(20), 99, "Should be 99")
```

This being my first question, I hope it's as complete and concise as it should be, and I am thankful for any pointers to help with said error.

EDIT: I changed the method to being public instead of private, and with that change, it now works. If I happen to find a good guide on how to write tests for private methods, I might link it here for future answer-seekers.

Comment: Did you already try just using `loose_hp` instead of `__loose_hp`?

Comment: Variables or functions with a double underscore are considered private and use name mangling (by prepending the class name, something like `_LivingBeing__loose_hp` in your case ), so you cannot access them directly by name. If you need to access a private attribute in a test, either it should not be private, or your test design is wrong.

Comment: @Schottky I just tried it, got the following error: AttributeError: 'LivingBeing' object has no attribute 'lose_hp'

Comment: So what did you try? To use `_LivingBeing__loose_hp`?

Comment: I tried ´self.livingbeing.lose_hp(20)´, my page hadnt yet loaded your comment when I responded. where would I put the _LivingBeing__lose_hp? it doesnt work with the following either: ´self.assertEqual(LivingBeing.__lose_hp(20), 99, "Should be 99")´, but maybe I put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: First, I would try to get rid of the private function, or change the test as I wrote. If that is not possible: you need the whole name, e.g. (`self._LivingBeing__lose_hp`).

Comment: If it's not private, it works! Thank you! I don't yet know how to write tests specifically for private functions, but I'll just find that out later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit too late but I was facing the same AttributeError as yours.
Removing double underscore from the beggining of the function I wanted to test helped me.

Comment: no worries about lateness, maybe this helps someone else :) thank you anyways!